# Cannot find module "Vector"

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

I've added this package to my project, but how do I import and use it? I've not come across a package with this setup before.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/Vector

https://github.com/willbailey/vector/blob/master/vector.js

I've tried:

```
import Vector from 'Vector';
```

But this produces: Cannot find module "Vector";

Comment: @Li357 but what's my import statement? I keep getting 'Cannot find module "Vector"'

Comment: Actually, there is an export -- see line 96

Comment: @Li357 Thanks, I revised my question to make it reflect the underlying problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do following for `Vector` library

```
var Vector = require('Vector/vector.js').Vector
```

I just tested it and it is working fine.

The problem is, `vector.js` is not set as default `import` from `npm` package. Following entry is missing from `package.json` file of `Vector`

```
"main": "vector"
```

Comment: Thanks! This solves my problem. Should I update my question?

Comment: Yes, you should otherwise you will keep getting negative votes.

Comment: This also works: `import { Vector } from 'Vector/vector';`

Comment: Yes it will, as I said in my answer. The problem is inside the package and not in your code.